# Python Pandas fillna with timedelta

Tags: pandas, time-series, nan

The standard fillna method of a pandas dataframe allows to limit for the next k entries in the matrix. Now I want to limit it not by the numbers of entries but instead for a certain time period (my index is a DatetimeIndex). My idea is that the values have a kind of decay, so I want to forward-fill the values instead of the NAs for let's say half an hour, but not further. How can I solve it?

```
index                  value_a   value_b    diff
2016-01-01 00:01:00      2.8       NaN       NaN
2016-01-01 00:06:00      2.8       5.4      -2.6
2016-01-01 00:11:00      NaN       5.4       NaN
2016-01-01 00:16:00      NaN       NaN       NaN
2016-01-01 00:21:00      NaN       5.4       NaN
```

In that example I e.g. would like to replace the NaN values only 14 minutes into the future, so that at 00:21:00 in column value_a the NaN remains while the other NaNs of value_a and also value_b disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is upsampling you can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.transform.html) and aggregate `first`:

```
#for testing 10Min
df = df.resample('10Min').transform('first')
print (df)
                     value_a  value_b  diff
index                                      
2016-01-01 00:01:00      2.8      5.4  -2.6
2016-01-01 00:06:00      2.8      5.4  -2.6
2016-01-01 00:11:00      NaN      5.4   NaN
2016-01-01 00:16:00      NaN      5.4   NaN
2016-01-01 00:21:00      NaN      5.4   NaN
```

Or maybe need `transform` + `ffill`:

```
df = df.resample('10T').transform('ffill')
print (df)
                     value_a  value_b  diff
index                                      
2016-01-01 00:01:00      2.8      NaN   NaN
2016-01-01 00:06:00      2.8      NaN   NaN
2016-01-01 00:11:00      2.8      5.4  -2.6
2016-01-01 00:16:00      2.8      5.4  -2.6
2016-01-01 00:21:00      NaN      5.4   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. It partially solves my problem because resampling as such seems to be a good approach. I thought about the problem in a rather stream-based manner so that the second approach (which propagates the NaNs) does not help much in my case. About the first approach I struggle to find what exactly the keyword 'first' does. Normally the [first](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first.html#pandas.DataFrame.first) method requires a parameter which in this case can not be provided?

Comment: I played around with the resample function and found the solution to my question: `df.resample('1T').asfreq().fillna(limit=10, method="ffill")` -- that way only the next ten minutes after a record are filled. Of course this is quite expensive and I need to make up my mind whether I really want to pursue this for my rather large amount of data (1 year, 300 columns).

Comment: What about `df.resample('1T').ffill(limit=10)` ?  I am on phone only, so cannot test it.

Comment: The output of that is not satisfying. It seems like `ffill` only fills the gaps the resampling created but does not exceed those borders -- this I am saying from visual inspection of the example, the true nature of this function deviates. But it is definitely different from the call I suggested in the comment above.

Comment: I am afraid, but better solution as `df.resample('1T').asfreq().ffill(limit=10)` what is same as `df.resample('1T').asfreq().fillna(limit=10, method="ffill")` I dont know :(

Comment: Well it serves the purpose and `df.resample('1T').asfreq().ffill(limit=10)` is an acceptable solution to me. I worked with it and I found my way how to deal with everything. Thanks a lot for your support!